# Unable to update from terminal or synaptic manager due to repository error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, error-handling

The following is the error I am encountering whenever I try to update ubuntu through the terminal, is there anything that can be done to fix it? I just started using ubuntu the last week and am still trying to get a hang of it.

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party software sources, so all security checks are your responsibility... ie. from your paste in the question I get to https://launchpad.net/~oguzhaninan/+archive/ubuntu/stacer which shows rather clearly what releases the PPA is good for, and that it hasn't received any attention since May 2019 which I'd see as a *warning sign* that would prevent me from wanting to use it (I may consider it if using *bionic* or 18.04 but I'd need to perform other checks before using it there too; your paste shows *jammy* thus you're 22.04).   PPAs being 3rd party mean security checks are on you.

Comment: @guiverc Stacer is legit software that has been recently included in the Ubuntu repositories. Indeed, the PPA is only for older releases.

Comment: Yeah I see it @ChanganAuto in *focal* & later [now!], and being Qt5 I'd hope I'd be familiar with it but alas I'm not :( , thanks.